# How to pass String as GLchar** (char**) parameter in glShaderSource?

Tags: opengl, swift

I have shader that stored in a String value:

```
    var myShader = 
    "    attribute vec4 a_position;" +
    "    void main() {" +
    "    gl_Position = a_position;" +
    "    }"

    glShaderSource(shader, GLsizei(1), myShader, nil)
```

The function glShaderSource has the bind signature:

```
    func glShaderSource(shader: GLuint, count: GLsizei, string: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<GLchar>>, length: UnsafePointer<GLint>)
```

When I try to pass the shader String to glShaderSource directly I get the error message:

```
    'String' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<GLchar>>'
```

How to pass String correctly? (xCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d))

Comment: `glShaderSource` takes an array of strings.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, of course. But single string can be passed as `char text[] = "..."; glShaderSource(s, 1, (char**)text, NULL)` in C. So I think single strnig can be passed in Swift by same way.
In any case I will be equally happy to learn how to pass single string or string array to function.

Comment: That's not correct. It's `glShaderSource(s, 1, &text, NULL)` in C.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You can pass char* reference to string if length = NULL and count == 1. This case described in OpenGL documentation. (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/580165-glshadersource-arguments/ -- look at example here)

Comment: Uh, no it doesn't. In the example you linked (`glShaderSource(obj, 1, (const char**)&code, &len);`) they are taking the address of the  string, just as my sample is. They just throw in a redundant cast.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Oh, sorry. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After half day search I found the work solution without compilation erros and bad memory access fails:

```
var cStringSource = (code as NSString).UTF8String
glShaderSource(shader, GLsizei(1), &cStringSource, nil)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. Besides what would be `code` in this case? In addition, where else are you using `stringfromutfstring`?

Comment: @Unheilig I use the code in this method https://gist.github.com/kreshikhin/b9c950b9ca982b7303f7 This code I use in production, so I did not had any problems in compilation.
And yes, you are right, stringfromutf8string is needless

Comment: Thanks for the gist (+1). I am still having problem with feeding up the last parameter. If you happen to know the correct syntax, please share. Thanks again.

Comment: @Unheilig Can you give a content of this syntax error?

I use the method from gist in such way `var vertexShader = compileShader(vertexCode, shaderType: GLenum(GL_VERTEX_SHADER))`
Where `vertexCode` is a typical vertex shader that stored in a typical swift String.
It's compiled ok in my project in xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002).

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3:**

```
let shaderStringUTF8 = shaderString.cString(using: String.defaultCStringEncoding)
var shaderStringUTF8Pointer = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(shaderStringUTF8)

glShaderSource(shaderHandle, GLsizei(1), &shaderStringUTF8Pointer, nil)
```

Comment: mistype in second line.

Comment: second line should modify to 
var shaderStringUTF8Pointer = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(shaderStringUTF8)

Answer (score 2):

CLchar is typealiased as a CChar in OpenGLs Swift implementation. Make the conversion like this:

```
var shaderString: String = "here's a String"
let cstring = shaderString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
glShaderSource(shader, GLsizei(1), UnsafePointer(cstring), nil)
```

Comment: I have got message "Value of optional type '[CChar]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?".

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use "!" after `cStringUsingEncoding()` to unwrap the result.